# Reliable means of exporting LibreOffice Calc 3 to LaTeX?

Tags: ubuntu, latex, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to export a LaTeX table from LibreOffice Calc. I am not using Excel because I am running Ubuntu.

I have tried using the calc2LaTeX macro, but have not been able to make it work for LibreOffice 3.

I am looking for something with the functionality of the Excel2LaTeX plugin (available [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex)).

Has anyone been able to do this using LibreOffice Calc 3?

Comment: I have `calc2latex` mostly working in LibreOffice 3 --- with glitches but basically working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficent way, but here's what I would do:

Save the spreadsheet in csv-format.

In LyX: File -> Import -> Table

Then: View -> View source.

Copy the code and paste it in your document.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer for now, but I still have to manually enter the gridlines for the tables, a loss of functionality in comparison to Excel2LaTeX plugin. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 4):

For an alternative try using `Gnumeric` (`sudo apt-get install gnumeric`). Once you have data entered ready to export, go to Data->Export Data->Export into Other Format. You can then choose either a LaTeX table fragment (just the data rows with & separators and \\ line endings) or a full LaTeX document with lots of parameters set by Gnumeric, and the table inserted.